# Unable to change emacs python indent

Tags: python, indentation

My Emacs's `python-indent-offset` is fixed at 2, even though I have the below code in my `init.el` to set it to 4. I used `C-h v` to describe the variable, it says its value is 2 and default is 4. I removed the below code and it's still 2. I've tried everything, but I can't seem to increase it to 4. Can someone help me out here?

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)

;; ----------------------- Python tab fix
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
        (setq tab-width 4)
        (setq python-indent-offset 4)))
```

Comment: Nothing about that looks particularly wrong, but there are couple of things you could check. Is `python-indent-guess-indent-offset` set to `t`? If so, then `python-mode` might look at your file and guess a different offset. Second, double check that nothing else in your init file is overriding these settings. You can comment out everything else and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Thanks @db48x. I think that somewhat helped, I disabled `python-indent-guess-indent-offset`. Now when I open emacs, it's `python-indent-offset` is 2, but if I eval my init.el once after opening, it gets set to 4 and stays at 4 until I close emacs.